# What's wrong with my FizzBuzz code for the codeacademy lesson?

Tags: javascript, fizzbuzz

I've looked for a lot of answers and even when I paste other people's code it doesn't seem to work. So I had like to know if my code is right and if my problem lies with the browser (or anything else), or if you can help me find my mistakes !

```
for (var i = 0, i <= 20, i++){
    if (i % 15 === 0){
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else if (i%3 === 0){
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if (i%5===0){
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoWK8.png)

Thank you !

Comment: Your syntax error is because you are using a comma to separate the stuff in your for loop instead of a semicolon.

Comment: Your doing `for( , , )` when you should be `for( ; ; )`

Comment: "... if my problem lies with the browser" - yes, because it's *never* your code. Makes *much* more sense that the problem would lie in something tested by millions of people over a span of many years :-) Sorry, not having a go at you, it's just the seemingly automatic assumption that the problem is elsewhere is a curious one to me.

Comment: You missed one big catch IMO. 15 is divisible by 3 and 5, so you can just have... if(i % 3) { console.log("Fizz"); } if(i % 5) { console.log("Buzz") } - if it is 15 it will output FizzBuzz - its a logic / thought process... Think about it!

Answer (score 1):

Statements in Javascript - i.e. `var i = 0;` - are separated by a semicolon, thus the conditional statements under which your code block are going to run should look like...

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
```

^ this.

```
for (var i = 0, i <= 20, i++)
```

^ rather than this.

edit:

You will probably encounter 'var' and ',' on the same line if you are declaring multiple variables in a single statement, which looks something like...

```
var a = "a",
    b = "b",
    c = "c";
```

note the statement still (and always will) end on a semicolon ;